# Datalab crashing despite high memory and CPU

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running a GCP Datalab VM with the following specs:

```
n1-highmem-16 (16 vCPUs, 104 GB memory)
```

Despite having a significant amount of RAM, when I try to run my training script with a dataset that is 300mb the kernel is crashing.  The code is training a NN and it is going through the training steps fine, but when evaluating on the test set it is crashing - not coming up with any errors.

Does anyone know why this is, or how I can find out?

EDIT:  The prompt that is coming up when it crashes says this:

"the kernel appears to have died. it will restart automatically jupyter notebook"

Comment: What do you mean by "the kernel is crashing"? If that were the case, you would have some sort of panic information to post. Please be specific and post all relevant information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael - I have added the only panic information that appears

Answer (score 2):

I add this as a comment:

Have you already tried this solution [1] last comment?

A good technique to try (I put this at the beginning of any script using tensorflow or keras). This prevents that resource exhausted error assuming you're batch size is within reason.

### import tensorflow as tf config = tf.ConfigProto() config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True Now when creating your session pass this config to it. sess = tf.Session(config=config)

[1] https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9829